# Stop moving turtles on the limit of specific patches with NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I'm new to NetLogo. In my simulation exercise, I want to stop fire and trees from being in some patches that represent a city.

This is some of my code.

```
to setup
    ca
    forest-fire
    city
end
to forest-fire
  create-forest trees[
    set color green
    set shape "square"
    set size 0.5
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
  create-fires pt-fire [
    set color red
    set shape "square"
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
end
to city  
  set a one-of (range -10 10)
  ask patches with [pxcor <= a and pxcor > a - 3 and pycor < a and pycor >= -2]
  [ set pcolor 6 ]
end
  ask forest-fire [
    ask neighbors with [pcolor = 6] [die]]
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution cuz of u thanks so the solution
for the trees
`ask patches with [pcolor = blue ] [ ask turtles-here[die] ]`
for the fire
`if any? patches with [count turtles-here >= 2 and pcolor = blue] [ stop ]`